# Phase difference of voltages at one side of a transformer

Tags: ac, transformer, oscilloscope, phase, phase-shift

Consider the circuit in picture

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFFQWK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Suppose that I measure VA and VB with respect to GND using an oscilloscope.

Will VA and VB be in phase or out of phase with respect to each other?

---

**Edit** : I tried to make measurement on a real circuit with the values of parameters as in picture (V1 is 220V). I measured VA and VB with an oscilloscope and I got

VA=6 V

VB=17.5 V

I used the MATH function on oscilloscope to get the difference VA-VB

VA-VB= 20 V

I did not measure directly the phase shift between VA and VB signals, but, from the amplitude I can deduce that pase shift d was such that

sqrt(VA^2+VB^2-2*VA*VB*cos(d))=20

Solving I find d around 106°.

Is this normal? I expected a 180° shift while I get a value which is much lower

Comment: Even after the question has already been accepted: Could you show us the waveforms for VA and VB measured in your circuit (simulated or mounted)?

Comment: @DirceuRodriguesJr I do not have the waveforms but I edited the question adding the measured amplitudes

Comment: What's the turns ratio for each transformer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the transformers shown are ideal, VA will be 180 degrees out of phase with VB. If not ideal then VA and VB will tend to be 180 degrees out of phase plus or minus a small error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Therefore, if I want to measure VA-VB (voltage across the transformer), can I connect VA to CH1, VB to CH2, then use INVERT button for VB and finally use ADD button? Or is it wrong to use the INVERT button here?

Comment: You can do it like that for sure. Or, you can move the 100 ohm resistor into the VA line thus grounding VB and then you just measure VA.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!! May I ask why VA and VB are out of phase (in the ideal case)? I know that a transformer can change or not the polarity of the input signal, but I did not find anything that can explain the phase shift between the voltages at the same side of the transformer.. Is this to be explained as an effect of the mutual inductance?

Comment: It's a s simple as one side being positive and the other side being negative and then of course that alternates. If both sides had the same polarity then there would be dc and ac together and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Many thanks! Nevertheless will VA and VB have the same amplitude? (Since I want VA-VB and these two are out of phase, I can simply say that VA-VB=+2VA if they had the same amplitude)

Comment: If there is zero current flowing in R1 (or R1 is zero ohms) then VA magnitude is the same as VB.

Comment: I tried to measure a real system like the one in picture and I found a phase shift of 106°, as added in the question. Is this value still explained by the "error" due to non ideal transformer? I must say that I visualized on oscilloscope waveforms that were not exactly sinusoidal but a little deformed, so can this be a factor in determine the phase difference?

Comment: This is due to non-idealities like saturation currents and leakage inductance. The distortions are probably due to saturation currents. When you performed "VA-VB= 20 V", was 20 volts what you expected?

Answer (score 2):

In generic terms, for a given voltage difference between the \$a\$ and \$b\$ points, there will be an infinite number of possibilities for the voltages \$v_a(t)\$ and \$v_b(t)\$to assume, when measured relative to a reference point. The **exact** setup will be given by the conditions of the circuit. For example, in the case of AC (sinusoidal), the \$v_{ab}(t)\$ voltage can be given as the difference:

$$ V_{ab}\cos\omega t = V_a\cos(\omega t+ \theta_a) -V_b\cos(\omega t+ \theta_b)  $$

including \$\theta_a\$ and \$\theta_b\$ phase shifts. Assuming that \$V_a\$ and \$\theta_a\$ are known and developing the right side, leads to:

$$ \theta_b = atan2(V_a\sin\theta_a,V_a\cos\theta_a-V_{ab})$$
$$ V_b = \sqrt{ V_a^2-2V_aV_{ab}\cos\theta_a+V_{ab}^2} $$

Considering TR1 turn ratio as 11, I simulate your circuit (obtaining results consistent with the above expressions) for two values of R1:

[image: Dirceu Rodrigues Jr. - 1]

The phase difference is 111.6 deg (\$\theta_a\$=64.19 deg and (\$\theta_b\$=175.78 deg). Changing R1 to 10R:

[image: Dirceu Rodrigues Jr. - 2]

Here the phase difference is 108 deg (\$\theta_a\$=54.69 deg and (\$\theta_b\$=162.69 deg). That is, many possibilities for phase difference other than 180 deg.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed answer!! May I ask which software you used for this simulation with digital oscilloscope?

Comment: It is the Proteus, widely used in educational establishments